# Python replace whole words without using regex

Tags: python, string, replace

I am wanting to replace whole words with another string without using regex. The `replace_all_whole_words1` does what I want, but I don't want to use regex and is only being used to test if my `replace_all_whole_words2` function is working correctly (it isn't).

```
import re
def replace_all_whole_words1(needle, replacement, haystack):
    needle = re.escape(needle)
    return re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % needle, replacement, haystack)

def replace_all_whole_words2(needle, replacement, haystack):
    i=0
    while len(haystack) > i:
        found_word = False
        found_word_start = i
        found_word_end = 0
        found_type = 0 # will repersent if we found,  word + " " or " " + word or " " + word + " " ()
        if i == 0:
            found_word = haystack[i:i+len(needle + " " )] == needle + " "
            found_word_end = i + len(needle) 
            found_type = 1
        elif i == len(haystack) - len(" " + needle):
            found_word = haystack[i:i+len(" " + needle)] == " " + needle
            found_word_end = i + len(" " + needle)
            found_type = 2
        else:
            found_word = haystack[i:i+len(" "  + needle + " " )] == " "  + needle + " "
            found_word_end = i + len(" " + needle + " ")
            found_type = 3
        if found_word:
            print(haystack, found_word_start, found_word_end, i, found_type)
            haystack = haystack[:found_word_start] + replacement + haystack[found_word_end:]

        i += 1
    return haystack



needle = "test"
replacement = "replaced"
haystack = "test test test testa atest"

print(
    replace_all_whole_words1(needle, replacement, haystack) == replace_all_whole_words2(needle, replacement, haystack)
)

print(
    replace_all_whole_words2(needle, replacement, haystack)
)
```

Comment: Use `split()` to split the string into a list of words. Then replace in the list. Finally use `join()` to convert it back to a string.

Comment: What has a regex ever done to hurt you? You have something that works, but do not want it. Is this a school project?

Comment: great idea @Barmar I will do this post the answer if you want and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of great and simpler answers here already that convert haystack to a list, perform the replacement and then convert it back to a string. If you still want to use haystack as a string throughout, check out this solution I made.

```
def replace_all_whole_words2(needle, replacement, haystack):
    # Counter to go through characters in haystack
    i = 0 
    
    # This will collect all chars separated by space as word
    word = '' 
    
    # len_needle will control replacement insertion and diff will adjust i after insertion 
    len_needle = len(needle)
    diff = len(replacement) - len_needle
    
    # Go through characters in haystack and replace needle with replacement
    while i < len(haystack):
        char = haystack[i]
        if char == ' ':
            if word == needle:
                haystack = haystack[:(i-len_needle)] + replacement + haystack[i:]
                
                # Adjust i so that you can continue from the next char after the space
                i += diff
                
            # Reset word to collect new chars
            word = ''
        else:
            word += char
        
        i += 1
        
    return haystack
```

Test:

```
needle = "test"
replacement = "replacement"
haystack = "test test test testa atest"

replace_all_whole_words2(needle, replacement, haystack)
```

Output:

```
'replacement replacement replacement testa atest'
```

Comment: good stuff, thanks for posting an answer relative to my function cool to see. also thanks for comments.

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert to list? Since you are just deleting words.

```
def replace_all_whole_words2(needle, replacement, haystack):
    l = haystack.split()
    for idx, word in enumerate(l):
        if word == needle:
            l[idx] = replacement
    return ' '.join(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, separating with split, using list comprehension and then re joining:

```
def replace_all_whole_words2(needle, replacement, haystack):
    word_list = haystack.split(' ')
    new_list = [replacement if word == needle else word for 
    word in word_list]
    return " ".join(new_list)
```